# asp menu with fixed horizontal sub menu

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am currently using asp menu and its sub menus.
Currently the sub-menus display vertically as we hover on to a menu item and disappear when we remove the mouse from it. i meed the control so that when i clicked the menu item then the sub-menu items should be displayed horizontally below the menu but they should not disappear when i remove the mouse from them.See the example.

If not clicked.

[image: If not clicked]

if Clicked on an item

[image]

Here "Events calender" is the menu item and the items below it "Monthly, Festival, Fun Trips" are the sub menu Items

The clicked item should be highlighted and the sub menu has to be displayed below it until I click on another menu Item.

Can you Help me???

Comment: On a completely side note, what do you use for your wireframes?

Comment: I do not know what are wireframes actually

Comment: Why don't you try Microsoft Visio